# How to query DHTMLX recursive event in SQL

Tags: sql-server, dhtmlx-scheduler

I've a requirement to schedule a recursive event with DHTMLX schedular and once user scheduled the event, other user can search by date to see if he is available on this date/time.

I'm able to save to database the recursive events without any issue. Now say user#1 scheduled an event and it's stored in database as below.

Start date:- 2015-03-11 10:00:00.000 
End Date:- 9999-02-01 00:00:00.000
Rec Type:- week_2___1,3,5#no

Now user#2 want to see if 2015-03-14 user#1 is available & which time he is available. how to run SQL query to get these details? I'm using sql server 2008 to build my project. 
can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done easily via SQL, at least there is no easy way. What language and a component do you use?
dhtmlxScheduler for ASP.NET provides a helper class for such cases, see the "GetOccurrences" item: 
http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/helpers-for-scheduler-net-in-use.aspx

And there is a helper that does the same in PHP:
https://github.com/DHTMLX/scheduler-helper-php